# phpMyAdmin affects zero rows but simulation affects 399

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running a simulation of this SQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET    post_content = ( Replace (post_content, 'src="http://', 'src="//') )
WHERE  Instr(post_content, 'jpeg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'jpg') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'gif') > 0 
        OR Instr(post_content, 'png') > 0;
```

Matched rows: 399

which matched 399 rows, but when i execute it, it affects zero.

is there an error i don't see ??

Comment: You mentioned a method `Replace()`, its a user defined method ?

Comment: Taking a guess. But I assume the simulated is the result of running select with them where clauses. Update 0 means the rows are the same as when you started. Eg after the replace the rows are in changed .  Try adding an check for instr('http://')

Answer (score 2):

Kindly refer this MYSQL [Manual for the UPDATE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) - it clearly tells...

If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.

So, if you run this query, MYSQL will understand that the value you're trying to apply is the same as the current one for the specified column, and it won't write anything to the database. This is the reason you are getting ZERO Rows affected...

Comment: from these examples of REPLACE inside an UPDATE: 
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement
it looks i am doing correctly.